# Django modelfield, how do I get the actual value?

Tags: python, django

If i have a model with a decimal field like this:

```
class Number(models.Model):
    decimal = models.DecimalField(max_digit=10, decimal_places=3)
```

And then I want to retrieve that value from a specific object:

```
n = Number(decimal=15.5)
n.save()
# Lets say n got id = 1
decimal = Number.objects.get(id=1).decimal
```

Now decimal is not 15.5, instead it's some sort of decimal datatype

```
Decimal('15.5')
```

So how do I retrieve the 15.5 from the decimal datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Decimal` object value by casting it to float.

Example:

```
dec = Number.objects.get(id=1).decimal
dec = float(dec)
```

Or even

```
dec = str(dec) #Please note this converts to  a string type.
```

One more way would be

```
dec = format(dec, '.2f') #Or change the precision to cater to your needs
```

Please note, it is not a good idea to use `decimal` as a variable name

Comment: Great this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: How do you do this in a query? Or do we have to loop and format each value?